Embed code in Webflow - CSS is not working with JavaScript
I just created my own slider and successfully connected with Webflow html div elements.
All works perfectly except this line of code
.nav-buttons button.active .selected-block { background-color: #14aed2; transition: background-color 0.3s ease; }
this selected-block css styling working but when my button is active this selected-block div inside my button dont change color.
I don’t know it’s something wrong in css code (this codes are tested in codpen.io) and working perfectly but in Webflow published site just active button style don’t.
If anyone had anyone same problem and sucesfully find solution I would be more then happy to hear it.
Best
Oh! I forget mention code is embed element should I use it in head section?
I'm using as embed code in this Webflow created div element
